# The library 'jna-4.2.2.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device in Android

Tags: java, android, jna

I have downloaded jna-4.2.2.jar from internet and now want to import this jar into my project . But when I am trying to import this jar into my projects , I am getting the following error .

```
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication] The library 'jna-4.2.2.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication] The following libraries were found:
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-arm/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-ppc64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-ppc64le/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/linux-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparc/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/freebsd-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/freebsd-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/openbsd-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-06-20 09:35:01 - FaceVerificationApplication]  - com/sun/jna/openbsd-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
```

How can I solve this error ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: try this gradle..... dependencies {
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.2.2'
} in your project

Comment: I am using eclipse .

Comment: Are you sure this is an error message, not a warning message? In any way you can open the jar file with a ZIP tool an delete the mentioned files from inside the JAR.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my problem . After adding  jna-4.2.2.jar ,  then in Eclipse I have to go to Window > Preferences > Android > Build > uncheck "Force error when external jars contain native libraries". Then this problem is solved .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your JAR contains native libraries that were not built for Android (but rather Linux, BSD, SunOS). You should look for JAR that contains ELFs (*.so files) that were built with Android NDK.

I'm not sure, but probably [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native) you can find proper native binaries.

Comment: After adding these jar , When I am trying to run my project , I am getting following error : Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

Answer (score 0):

The base jna.jar includes binaries for a range of desktop platforms for convenience.  Sometimes specific deployment requirements demand a different configuration, at which point it's up to you to include just the code and/or binaries that are appropriate for your situation.

Android requires that you specifically load your native libraries in a particular way as part of your application build and deploy.

You need to explicitly add *just* the android binary, and omit the others from your build.